# Retrieving specific data from firebase

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve some data from my **Firebase** `database` but I can't get it done. First I created `.json` file with data and then imported it into **Firebase**. It looks like that but it is much longer:

[image]

Now I am trying to print out all the "Brands" like "CATCH", "CRAFTED SNUS" etc but I can't for some reason.

Thats how I am doing it. I am loading it inside `viewDidLoad()`. I know it is not right to do but just for testing:

```
func fetchBrands(){
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if !snapshot.exists() { return }

        //print(snapshot)

        if let snusBrand = snapshot.value!["Brands"] as? String {
            print(snusBrand)
        }

        // snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("full_name").value as! String
    })


}
```

What I am doing wrong? I also set the `read` and `write` rules from **Firebase** to `true`

The only thing it prints is this:

[image]

Comment: what error are you getting? what does `print(snusBrand)` prints?

Comment: @adolfosrs The only thing it prints is some long text about proxy etc. Check edit.

Comment: Use `snapshot.key` to get the key of each document.

Answer (score 2):

You can try updating the ref to point directly to the child Brands and iterating on the returned snapshot like this:

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Brands")

ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot -> Void in
    for brands in snapshot.children {
      print(brands)
    }
  })
```

Comment: hmm, try: `ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").child("Brands")`

Comment: Should use `child_added` event and `key` property of each snapshot.

Comment: Wow finally it prints something but it prints everything I have inside my database.

Comment: `print(brands.key)`

Comment: But it's very bad approach, because you loading ALL child data. You should flatten your json tree